# Recording Programming Time - Write it or download it?

Tags: .net

I was about to write a program that just tracks the time I spend coding.  Then I thought there must already be some sort of feature in my IDE(VS 2008) or something to download for free.  Basically, I just need to record the start time, end time and a subject line.  I need either a free option or an option using Visual Studio 2008, which I already have.  I am a one person coding team.  I am not very familiar with Version Control.  If this is already a feature of every version control system in the world, please don't beat me over the head.  Just let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeremy

Comment: Do you want the timing itself be done by the app by you clicking start/stop?  Or you'll handle the timing manually and you're just trying to document the categories in a log and need summaries?

Comment: For that matter, is there any app that measures something like an accumulated time how long a window is in focus? So you can see that you spend 1:20 a day in email, 4:40 in Firefox, and :44 in Emacs.... and realize there's probably a problem there if you think you're coding all day?

Comment: @Arno - Yep. Timesnapper - see my answer. And, no, I don't work for them, I just like the product :-)

Comment: I've said this before (in the dozen or so other times this question has been asked on SO :-) - nothing beats just writing down the time and activity in a big red book. The best way to work is to do *one* thing for a couple of hours, not chop and change to the point where you're worried about the time difference between clicking a button and writing down a line of text. If you work like that, recording time is the least of your problems. If you don't work like that, you don't need some fancy application. Voting to close as a dupe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891510/how-do-you-track-time-spent-working-on-a-project - you could also have found it by clicking on the close link and selecting "exact duplicate" to get a list of duplicates given to date (just make sure you cancel out unless you're certain you want it to close).

Comment: And you don't *have* to delete it. I'm not a god here. If another four people don't agree with me, your question will stay (as it should: SO is a community-driven site and, as egotistical as I can be sometimes, I am only a small part of that community).

Comment: In the other question the person said they would prefer a command line tool.  I am not interested in a command line tool.  Additionally, I think the answers here meet my needs a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Fogbugz with a plugin.  Worked great for me.  There is a free version for startups with 2 or fewer users.  Timesnapper  also sounds like a great tool, but Fogbugz met my modest needs the best.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused. Where do you want to put this info? In the source code, or somewhere else? If you just need it for billing and for preparing your timesheets, you can't go past [Timesnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/), it is **the** awesome.

Comment: Just need it for billing.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: How does Timesnapper fare with multiple monitors? Are they supported? This seems like a pretty useful app, and I might use it myself it if can handle two widescreens.

Comment: No worries. Timesnapper should do you well then. There's a free version as well that has less features, but should have enough for you to sit back at the end of the day and accurately prepare your timesheet.

Comment: @jrista - it goes fine with multiple monitors, you end up with big screenshots :)

Answer (score 2):

I came accross FusionDesk a while back while reading [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/). It has a free edition, however, I am not sure if the free edition supports time tracking or not. Its a pretty good product, and the pay version isn't terribly priced, in case your interested.

http://www.fusiondesk.com/

EDIT:

I also forgot the great staple of CodeProject: ToDo List. This sucker is the top project at www.codeproject.com, and has been for years. It lets you organize your tasks and track time, and its free to boot:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at FreshBooks,

http://www.freshbooks.com/

It's free (for personal use at least) and provides time tracking functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it: [Keeping a timesheet](http://xwells.blogspot.com/2005/10/keeping-timesheet.html).

Comment: This is how I am currently doing it, but it's not the most efficient use of my time.  I could write a program where I only have to press one start/stop toggle button instead of entering all of the times.  The only thing I would have to enter is the subject.

Comment: If you put .LOG on the first line of the file then Notepad.exe appends a new timestamp automatically whenever you reopen the file (so you never need to enter the time).

Comment: That's cool to know.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @ChrisW: I've been using Notepad for over 12 years, and did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: @chrisW That's great and really useful. Had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [TodoList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx)?
Task breakdown, time tracking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) can track app use for you...it has an amusing feature where your productivity is compared to the average across everyone using it...

Answer (score 0):

Simple little tray application with icon indicating status (running/stopped) and a hotkey for starting / stopping, window pops up on start to enter a subject.

log to xml, text  or database or where ever is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a google desktop gadget that you could use for this:
http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/tasklistandtimer.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a small Java program I wrote for project time tracking:

http://tech.dolhub.com/Program/TimeKeeper

Answer (score 0):

I heard about Timesnapper on Hanselminutes: [get it here.](http://www.timesnapper.com/)
It records your activities into pictures that you can analyse later for time sheets and stuff.